# How to implement syntax sugar in OO

Tags: php, static-methods

#### The Problem

I regularly find myself writing the same code over and over again.

For example if I want a value from a nested array structure I end up writing something like this:

```
$config = function_to_get_nested_array();
$node = $config;
foreach(array('vendor','product','config','leave') as $index => $key){
    if(! isset($node[$key])){
      //throw exception
    }
    $node = $node[$key];
}
```

I would prefer to have something like

```
$config = function_to_get_nested_array();
$node = get_node($config, 'vendor/product/config/leave');
```

But how do I implement it?

#### Possible Solutions

1. I could implement a function as I did above. *BUT* my packages heavily rely on autoloading and are purely OO. Right now I just have to clone an submodule in the right directory and everything works fine.
2. I could implement this where I need it. *BUT* this means I have to implement it countless times in independent projects.
3. I could use a [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), if I was not stuck with PHP 5.3. Not an option for me.
4. I could implement a static service provider.

For various reasons static classes and methods are usually a bad choice, but I am tempted
to do so in this case.

```
use vendor\product\helpers\ArrayTree as Tree
...
$config = function_to_get_nested_array();
$node = Tree::getNode($config, 'vendor/product/config/leave');
```

Looks *very* tempting, because it supports autoloading and namespaces.

#### The Question

Is there a better solution to implement this kind of helper functions?

Comment: Why not simply implement it as a class? Like your Tree example. `(new Tree( $myArray))->get('vendor\product\...')`

Comment: I do not see how this is better than using a static method. I still have the same amount of coupling. So why bother creating an instance?

Comment: Ah I see... my thought was you just disliked static methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good scenario to use a static method.

Static methods can be problematic since they are essentially **global functions**, i.e. the call is hard wired to that specific class. During unit testing it is hard to replace a static method with a mocked one.

However, in your case, `getNode` is a pure stateless **utility function**. Go ahead and implement that tempting solution.

```
class ArrayTree {
    public static function getNode($array, $path) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `it is hard to replace a static method with a mocked one` -- You don't have to, if you never hold state or cause side effects.

Comment: @RobertHarvey true :)